# Turn array of maps to a map of all the underlying map key-value pairs

Tags: groovy

I have the following code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

​def a = '[{"a":"1234"},{"b":"5678"}]'
def documentList = new JsonSlurper().parseText(a)
```

From this, I want a piece of code that turns this documentList to a map like this:

```
["a":"1234","b":"5678"]
```

So that I can check in the map using the `containsKey` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def inputJson = '[{"a":"1234"},{"b":"5678"}]'

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def jsonArray = jsonSlurper.parseText(inputJson)

def map = [:]
jsonArray.each { jsonObj ->
    map.putAll(jsonObj)
}

println map
```